# How to print out all the values inside object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm using this function to write all the values inside object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function print_r(theObj){ 
       if(theObj.constructor == Array || theObj.constructor == Object){ 
          document.write("<ul>") 
          for(var p in theObj){ 

             if(theObj[p].constructor == Array || theObj[p].constructor == Object){ 
                document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+typeof(theObj)+"</li>"); 
                document.write("<ul>");
                document.alert(p.typeof(theObj)); 
                print_r(theObj[p]); 
                document.write("</ul>") 
             } else { 
                document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+theObj[p]+"</li>"); 
                //alert(p+" "+theObj[p]);
             } 
          } 
          document.write("</ul>") 
       } 
    }  </script>
```

It prints out values inside object like

```
print_r({"total":4,"offset":0});
```

But how can it be tweaked to print values if there is another object, like this:

```
print_r({"total":4,"offset":0,"memberData":{"firstName":"joe","lastName":"smith"}});
```

Comment: easy: `if (typeof theObj[p] == 'object') { print_r(theObj[p]); } else { /* do your normal printing stuff */ }`. It's called [recursion](http://google.com/search?q=recursion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to output the object neatly on the screen you can do

```
function print_r(obj) {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + '</pre>';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5rr8naLo/1/)

Comment: and if you need just-in-time, quick checks, you can just type the object's name in the developer console.